# Is the question creator notified if a close vote has been cast?

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, notifications

I often vote to close questions regarding database administration as off-topic->better suited for dba.stackexchange.com

The migration process can take ages till 4 more users vote to close.
To save the OP some time I'm just wondering if it's necessary to write him a comment, that he might get better answers at the sister site, or if he gets notified anyway about the close vote, although it's just one. If this is not the case, wouldn't it be a nice feature?

Comment: Only for duplicates via a comment.

Comment: Or custom close reasons, again via auto-comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.  The author of the question does not get any notification except in 2 special cases (which really aren't notifications of the close vote, but notifications of the resulting comment)

- Duplicates via the "possible duplicate" comment.  This also means that duplicate closures without a comment (specifically mod closures) do not generate a notification.
- Close votes that are from custom close reasons since that generates an auto-comment.

In both cases, subsequent votes will not generate a notification since the comment already exists unless a different comment is generated.

In addition, users with less than 250 rep will not even be able to see the close votes until the question is closed, so they will not receive any feedback until the question is closed.

So if you see a good question that is off-topic for Stack Overflow, but on-topic for DBA, then a comment would be the quickest method to notify the OP of that fact.

Comment: Concerning the last paragraph, wouldn't that call for a other flag and asking the moderator to move the question there?

Comment: You can vote for migration to some sites, such as DBA.  Otherwise, if you can't vote for migration, then yes, you should **flag** for migration.  Don't vote to close as off-topic because you think it should be migrated somewhere not in the list.

Comment: @martin Given the volume of flags that mods get, it certainly won't be the quickest.  And regardless, the mods are busy enough, so it seems that the community should try to move it first, and only if that doesn't work should a moderator be asked.

Answer (score 3):

*psubsee2003*'s answer has already outlined that indeed user are not notified of pending close votes.  Instead, they are notified of comments to their question which happens to be a direct result of two of the close vote options:

- Closing as duplicate
- Custom close reason

And low rep users won't even be able to determine that close votes exist at all.

The question though is, *should* users be notified?  I don't think they should.  I don't see it being particularly constructive.  As long as the user is notified when their question is put on hold (they are, right?), this should suffice.

A vote to close is just that--a vote.  It doesn't mean anything until there are five of them.  And when there are five votes to close, the question isn't deleted--it's put on hold.  The whole point of being on hold is...

> Five members of the community or at least one moderator believes this question is off-topic for some specific reason which is now gray-boxed between the questions and comments.  You, the asker, need to address this issue before we consider re-opening it.

If you want to give the user an early warning that you think the question is doomed toward being put on hold if not edited, leave a *specific* comment about exactly what the question's problems are and let the user try to address those specific issues.

The closure reasons tend to be relatively broad and aren't necessarily going to apply directly to the question you cast the vote on.  So if you want to help the asker, leave a constructive comment.